# Get username from ID

Tags: laravel

I have a blade template in a Laravel 5.5 app that is returning a user ID integer

I am looking for a way to get the users name from that value within the blade template

The value is just saved in the table and there is no relationship setup, is there a way to get the username without having to set up a relationship?

** UPDATE **

My products controller looks like this...

```
public function index()
{

    $users = User::all();

    $products= Product::all();

    return view('products.index',compact('products', 'users'));     
}
```

So now I have the users available inside the blade template but now I need to get the user from the id that is contained in produts

Comment: Why not return the user object to the view and just output what you need?

Comment: Is it for authenticated user ?? then try Auth::id();

Comment: If youre nit returning it to the server there ia nothing you can do with that ID

Comment: He return the user $users = User::all();. I guess you do a foreach in the blade? can we see the blade code? it should be smth like $user->name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller that's passing the user data to the view, you can either pass the entire `$user` object and print it in your view like `{{ $user->name }}` or set yourself a variable that holds just the username and pass that in for however you're using it.

I would do the first one though, something like:

```
public function index()
{
    $user = User::where('id',$id)->firstOrFail();
    return view('dashboard.index', compact('user'));
}
```

Or if you're getting all users from the database, an example would be:

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::all();
    return view('dashboard.index', compact('users'));
}
```

Then in your view you can do

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    {{ $user->name }}
@endforeach
```

**Edit**

Since seeing your updated question, you would benefit from making a relationship between your `users` and your `products`. So, you would say that a `user has many products` and that a `product belongs to a user`.

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the products for the user.
     */
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }
}
```

And then

```
class Product extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the user that is assigned to the product
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Once you have set this up, you can loop through your products and get the username like this:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    {{ $product->user->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: @fightstarr20 I've just added a second example for you

Comment: I am doing this inside of a 'products' controller like this...    public function index()
    {
      
        $products = Product::all();
        return view('products.index',compact('products'));     
    }

Comment: Not currently, I am trying the first example but i'm getting undefined variable id.  Trying to resolve now

Comment: @fightstarr20 it's hard to give you a fully working solution without knowing how you're using it or how you're trying to use it. If you update your question with some code examples to show the desired outcome I can clarify this a bit. These are just examples to point you in the right direction at the minute

Comment: You need to set up a relationship really, that would be the proper way of doing it @fightstarr20

Comment: @fightstarr20 added a relationship example for you

Comment: Thank for your help, was trying to avoid it but realtionship seems to be the correct solution :)

Comment: @fightstarr20 no problem at all, relationship is definitely the best way to go, this is exactly what they're for :)

Answer (score 3):

Create helper file: follow this rule to make it : https://laravel-news.com/creating-helpers

and make one function like this:

```
function getUsername($uerId) {
 return \DB::table('users')->where('user_id', $userId)->first()->name;
}
```

and call this function from your view like this :

```
 {{getUsername($id))}} //it will print user name;
```

Comment: Or, do the logic in the controller and pass it to the view, without needing to create helpers or additional files

Comment: Helper looks good, doing the logic in the controller sounds better though.  Currently I just return using ::all, reading up now on how to customise the output from the controller

Answer (score 2):

```
{{\App\User::findOrFail($id)->name}}
```

Comment: Ideally view's shouldn't handle logic

Comment: If the user doesn't exist, that method will throw an HTTP exception with redirection. Since the headers were already sent -- it's already rendering/outputting the view -- you'll probably get a warning message similar to `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent`.

Answer (score 0):

`Auth::user()->name` if user is online. if not you must have controller function like:

```
$users = User::all();

and in blade 

@foerach($users as $user)
{{$user->name}}
@endforeach
```